# Argument passing and conditional execution does not work in make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have attached the sample of the make file.

```
# SELECT TARGET OPERATING SYSTEM 
override OS = LINUX
#OS = WINDOWS

CC = gcc
SRC_DIR = src
INC_DIR = inc
OBJ_DIR = obj
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -I$(INC_DIR)

# CONDITIONAL COMPILATION
ifeq ($(OS), "WINDOWS")
SERIAL = Winsrcfile
CLEAR = cls
endif
ifeq ($(OS), "LINUX")
SERIAL = Linsrcfile
CLEAR = clear
endif
```

I am trying to achieve this...

```
make OS=WINDOWS      // compile for windows
```

or

```
make OS=LINUX       // compile for linux
```

from linux shell or windows command prompt and want default to be linux, if OS is not specified while executing 'make'. But the ifeq returns false in both cases, generating an error 'No rule to make target'. I read [override directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive) & [conditional syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html#Conditional-Syntax) but it seems i havent got a clear idea of it. I have tried every alternate syntax of conditional syntax. But get error 'invalid syntax in conditional. Stop'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make doesn't distinguish quotation marks. What you should do instead is:

```
ifeq ($(OS),LINUX)
# do stuff
endif
```

What's actually done here is that the arguments are expanded and then compared literally. `$(OS)` expands to the value of the variable and `LINUX` expands to `LINUX`. Your example would for example require `make OS='"Linux"'` in order to work

Comment: maybe override isn't necessary here, as command line arguments override the variable value throughout the makefile